# Apache Config setProperty Method is it write in memory or is it rewrite old configuration?

Tags: java, apache-config

This about the java dependencies named Apache Configuration. 
what does setProperty() do, is it would write in memory or it would rewrite the old configuration value on the file.

im already reading the file on [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/Configuration.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) cannot get the details.

Thanks for any suggestion